# Unknown cause of one port that is forwarded

Tags: windows, port-forwarding

**TLDR**

One port is open on the pc (windows) and I cannot figure why (how to close it/how to open more)

**Background**

Over the summer, I had to setup port forwarding on my pc and the home router (port 54350), which worked fine. A few months later I went back to college, but since I was not allowed to setup port forwarding on school network, I assumed there's nothing I can do. A couple days ago I booted up the program that required port 54350 again, and to my surprise it was working. But here's the problem...

**Problem**

I cannot figure out why port 54350 is open, but no other port is open.

**Attempted solutions**

My initial reasoning is that, since this one port is open in my home and at school, it must be due to the settings of my computer. Hence I poked around with Windows Firewall, the advanced settings (Inbound/outbound Rules) does not have the number 54350 anywhere, and after turning on network discovery, port 80 becomes open, but no other port (besides 54350) is open.

Then I tried to Google the cause of this, but all I could gather are "Allow the program through the firewall" and "Set up new rules in the advanced Settings", which I've tried (I tried turning off firewalls as well). Didn't work either. Other sources showed tutorials of setting up port forwarding on routers, but that's not I was looking for (I just wanted to know why this port is open and how can I open more).

I think I am missing something obvious here (but it might very well not be), so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

My apologies for not being more clear in the question. What I meant was, after configuring the port-forwarding part on my home router (Using the current PC in the process), port 54350 is the only port that is open on my PC (when I plug it into the school network, at least), and hence no other port is reachable. The school network probably wouldn't have this port open for no apparent reason, so I reasoned that my PC must have some settings that "notifies" the school network to forward port 54350. I'm confused on what setting could possibly be causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up a few things. You initially set up port forwarding on your home router and then return to that same router some months later and you still see the same port forwarding in effect, right? That is no big surprise, unless the router was changed, reset or something else then it still has the same config as when you left for school.

As for your PC, a PC (client) does not do port forwarding, it opens up a port and attaches a listening process (server program) to it. You can use the inbuilt program `netstat` to see what ports are open (it does not take firewall into account though) and what processes are listening on that port.

Basically, a port is open on your PC as soon as some process asks for that port to be open and has privilages to do so. A router on the other hand does not forward ports unless it has been told to do so assuming it is NAT-ing of course, like most home routers do.

As for the school network, then you could not get any outside computer to connect to your computer (unless through third party connections like TeamViewer or something like that), right? That is no big surprise either since that network is totally in the hands of the school network administrator and he controls what goes through that network.

Hope that is clear and addresses your confusion.

EDIT:

Even though you see from outside that port 54350 is open it does not mean that it routes to your computer. The campus network probably has one IP number to the outside world and then has a router (or more then one router probably) that routes all incoming and outgoing traffic to the clients and servers on the campus. This is called NAT (network address translation). It basically hides all computers on the campus behind one IP address. So when you use an outside scanner to check for your open port it scans the public IP address and sees that port open (to what it connects it doesn't know). Even though your computer accidentally uses the same port it doesn't mean that an outside source would connect to your computer if it connected to port 54350 on the public IP of your school. Perhaps the network admin has put up port forwarding to another computer on that port.

Comment: Thanks for the long reply! I'm sorry for the confusion and I've clarified the question. I was attempting to give out more details, my bad if it was not clear enough!

Comment: Quite ok, we all begin asking questions in some muddled way :-)

Comment: Regarding that, I discovered that port 54350 is open because I was using a torrenting software, so I assumed that it is working (I was connectable). But you could be right, I should probably look into this further.